# What can POST do, GET can't do?

Tags: get, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

I read from a book that POST is used to send data to the server that somehow causes a change in the state of the server, such as inserting data in a database. And GET is used for data retrieval that doesn't change anything on the server.

I actually don't quite understand the above. Can someone demostrate it with an example? The example would show that if I replace $_POST by $_GET, the code wouldn't work.

Am I right to say that we can do without GET but we can't do without POST?